# Validating a form for email exploits is not working

Tags: php, oop, validation

I have a contact form in my website. I made a class to handle the whole process. 
But there is something not working in it.

I have 2 functions to check for exploitation and they are not working. I don't know what's wrong with them, so here they are :

```
private function _validateExploit($val) {
    $exploitPattrens = array('content-type', 'to:', 'bcc:', 'cc:', 'document.cookie', 'document.write', 'onclick', 'onload', '\n', '\r', '\t', '%0A', '%0D', '%08', '%09');

    foreach ($exploitPattrens as $exploit) {
        if (strpos($exploit, $val) !== false){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function isExploit () {

    if(call_user_func_array(array($this, '_validateExploit'), $_POST)) {
          echo $errorMsg;
     }
 }
```

When I call `isExploit()` it always return false, no matter what I give it as an input.

I guess there is something wrong with the `call_user_func_array`, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`strpos($exploit, $val)` should be `strpos($val, $exploit)`

You also have `echo $errorMsg;` but `$errorMsg` is never defined.

And I think you probably want `array_walk` ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php ) rather than `call_user_func_array`. I would just loop through $_POST rather than use either of those functions though. I don't think they really buy you anything in this case - and they might not return values the way you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I used `array_filter` because `array_walk` always returns true on success and in this case it must succeed to be able to validate. `array_filter` returns what the function returns. Thanks for pointing me :D

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `$_POST` variable to the function.  `$_POST` is an array as the [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function requires, but you are not treating it like an array in the `_validateExploit` function.  You are treating it like a string.  You need to loop through the $val array as well testing each item in that array or just pick one.  You also have your haystack and needle reversed in [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) as indicated in another answer.

```
private function _validateExploit($val) {
    $exploitPattrens = array('content-type', 'to:', 'bcc:', 'cc:', 'document.cookie', 'document.write', 'onclick', 'onload', '\n', '\r', '\t', '%0A', '%0D', '%08', '%09');

    foreach ($exploitPattrens as $exploit) {
        foreach ($val as $itm) {
            if (strpos($itm, $exploit) !== false){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good catch of the call_user_func_array() issue. If the OP rewrites `_validateExploit()` your way, he can just call `$this->_validateExploit($_POST)`

Comment: They could do that, but calling it using `call_user_func_array()` allows them the flexibility of calling any function that they want in a loop passing in the $_POST array as an argument.  The `if` statement there may be just a snippet of the real code with the name of the function added in for our benefit.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, I fixed the 'strpos()'. But I actually thought that `call_user_func_attay()` would do the job for me instead of going through nested loops which are bad for performance.

Comment: Well.. the point is and was that `$_POST` is an array.  You will have to walk it, loop through it, or pick individual elements to test in your function.